# ansible iterate over loop

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

What is wrong when iterating over a collection in ansible?

When executing `ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local main.yml` the error is

```
- name: echo kerberos
        shell: echo "addprinc -pw {{ item.password }} {{ item.username }}"
             ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

But for me it looks like I am already correctly following these rules.

Here my minimal example:

main.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: echo kerberos
        shell: echo "addprinc -pw {{ item.password }} {{ item.username }}"
        with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

users.yml

```
---
users:
  - username: test_user
    password: test_user
    sn: User
    uid: 50001
    gid: 100
  - username: test_user1
    password: test_user
    cn: Test User1
    sn: User1
    uid: 50002
    gid: 100

user_groups:
  - cn: access1
    gid: 100001
    users:
      - test_user1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful with padding in YAML:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: echo kerberos
      shell: echo "addprinc -pw {{ item.password }} {{ item.username }}"
      with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

`shell` and `with_items` are aligned with `name`.